# Compare text in a Memo with another Memo?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In a Form, I have dropped 3 memo controls: `memo1`, `memo2`, and `memo3`.

When I type a full sentence question into `memo2`, an answer that is stored in `memo1` should be displayed in `memo3`.

For example, suppose in `memo1` I wrote:

```
what is your name?=my name is john
```

When I type `what is your name?` into `memo2`, `my name is john` should appear in `memo3`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Memo1` contains `name=value` pairs.  The `TMemo.Lines` property is a `TStrings` object, and `TStrings` has some useful properties for working with `name=value` pairs.  In your example, the simpliest solution would be to use the question in `Memo2` as the `Name` parameter of the `TStrings.Values[]` property, eg:

```
var
  question: string;
  answer: string;
begin
  question := Trim(Memo2.Text);
  answer := Memo1.Lines.Values[question];
  Memo3.Text := answer;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy for your help,I tried like your eg. But I couldn't .can you show me your project if you don't mind.As I hv search in Google n I got one which is similar abit but the think is that when I type any single letter in keyboard  before completing  my sentence...it display answer.so is there any way to do.

Comment: Title:spliting memo line into other two memo..By Stiphen  . reply by David heffernan.....Here is the code..var s:string; p:integer; begin s:=memo1.Text; p:=pos('=',s); memo2.Text: =copy(s,1,p-1); memo3.Text: =copy (s,p+1,maxint); end;

Comment: @Meitei: I forgot that the `TStrings.Text` property returns a `string` that has a line break on the end of it.  I have updated my example to account for that.  Now `Memo3` displays `my name is john` as expected.

Comment: Remy I took your code n tried but its not working..As I expected.But anyways I appreciate you as u thought of helping me...The code which David heffernan post that works ...

Comment: Remy do you know how to create video converter in Delphi...can you suggest me any website which has source code or if you hv code  to make video converter in Delphi with listview, button n combobox for selecting formate like mp3,3gp,mp4...you can mail here also...Software designed@gmail.com.

Comment: @meitei If my code above is not working for you, then you are not using it correctly. I tested it, it works fine. Besides, David's code that you showed won't help you once you start adding more `question=answer` pairs in `Memo1`. You need something that can search strings, not just split them. The code I gave you does both at one time.

Comment: @meitei "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*"

Comment: Maybe I hv not done correctly,okay let me try again n let you know the result.... By the way where  do I put the above code to work correctly.Is it under form1.memo2change or I hv to add a button on form to work.

Comment: @Meitei: put it wherever you need it.  Do you really need real-time updates as the user is typing? I used a button for testing.

Comment: Ya I need real time updates as user typing.I  tried as button n add ur code but it says..the parameter is incorrect.I don't know y.am working on rad studio xe10 settle.Should it be difference in Delphi 7 n rad studio xe10 settle. If u want to see my working project I can sent you.I don't know what mistake I hv done.Can you correct it plzz.

Comment: @meitei you can use an `OnKeyPress` or `OnChange` event to trigger the code. There is nothing in the code I gave you that would cause a parameter error, so it has to be a mistake in your own code. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36751479/edit) to show your latest code, or post a new question.

Comment: .your code works perfect. I was incorrect. I didn't put the proper input as same it is in memo1 but now its working. Am very thankful to you for guiding me... Thanks alot.